# Is it possible to install Android on a PC?

Tags: installation, android-x86

Is it possible to install Android on a PC?  If so, how would this be accomplished?

Comment: You can run the emulator on the PC....  Otherwise... you'd have to make drivers specific to the hardware you are running it on?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The HowToGeek has a set of instructions on how to [Run Android on Your Netbook or Desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22665/run-android-on-your-netbook-or-desktop/) here. It uses the Android builds from [Android-x86.org](http://www.android-x86.org/download) but I don't know how active that project still is?

However if you just want to try Android out you're probably far better off just [using the emulator on your PC](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21831/how-to-test-drive-google-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone/).

Comment: Well, I've got a project for this weekend now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Checkout [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) or [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Answer (score 6):

I bought an Acer Aspire netbook, and it has Windows 7 and Android 2.1 pre-installed.

Comment: Which model of Aspire have you got? Is it fully functional Android? Does it come with the Android Market and the other Google-only apps?

Comment: @GAThrawn it's an Acer Aspire One D255. Actually, I am an Android-noob, but I think it is a fully functional Android. Android Market Store is not preinstalled. I had to install it myself.

Comment: @GAThrawn But Android is clearly not made for use on a netbook. I can not scroll with the touchpad, and I can not increase mouse-acceleration, so the mouse is pretty slow.

Comment: @GAThrawn Firefox is also preinstalled, and Flash works out of the box.

Comment: @Natrium thanks for filling us in with more details. Android shouldn't have any big design disadvantages for running as a 2nd OS on a Netbook, unfortunately it sounds like your problems are more down to Acer not spending time getting the drivers for their hardware right on Android. Have you looked to see if they've released any updates for it?

Comment: @GAThrawn no, I did not check that yet. Good idea anyway; I will check it out and post a reply here.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to run android on PC

1. Using Official Android Emulator
2. [BlueStacks](http://bluestacks.com/)
3. [YouWave](http://youwave.com/)
4. [AppSurfer](http://www.appsurfer.com/) (run Android app in browser)
5. [Android-x86 Project](http://www.android-x86.org/)
6. [Windroy](http://www.socketeq.com/)
7. [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I came across another way to install Android on a PC from [MakeUseOf](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/googles-android-mobile-platform-computer-live-cd/) via [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/trying-google-mobile-android-on-my-pc) Android Enthusiasts question, and thought I'd post it as an alternative answer.  It's a live CD called, appropriately enough, "Live Android."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I am running a fully functional Android 4.0.4 (ICS) on my *Acer ASPIRE ONE D255E*.

Amazing how fully functional it is, out-of-the box, without me having to spend any time tweaking or hacking.

Use these up-to-date instructions on [How To Install Android On Your Netbook](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-android-netbook/).