# Trying google mobile android on my pc

Tags: android-x86

In order to try google mobile android on my pc ([See this Website](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/googles-android-mobile-platform-computer-live-cd/)) I downloaded the file liveandroidv0.3.iso and used the 'Universal Netboot Installer' software to write the image on USB device. After restarting all works correctly until I get the image 'Live android' but the OS doesn't launch and nothing happens! This can be due of what?

Best,

Comment: In other words, i'm stuck at this step :  http://i55.tinypic.com/nnw7li.jpg

Comment: Hi again! Worked for me moments ago when i tried again (But with Virtualbox) by setting more virtual memory. Though still doesn't work with CD live boot or USB device! 

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [the Android emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) if you want to experiment with Android without buying a device.  LiveAndroid isn't supported by Google and it hasn't been updated in quite a while.  It could be that your video card is not supported.

I'd also recommend using VMWare Player instead of VirtualBox if you really want to use LiveAndroid.